# How to scrape dynamic data with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, jquery, html, dom

first let me say that I have read over numerous "scrapping" threads on here and none have been of help to me.  I also checked around the internet for days and now I am getting close to the wire I am hoping someone can shed some light on this for me.

I am using PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser to scrape some data from a page.  The url I am working with serves dynamic content and I can not seem to get anything to work to pull that content in.  I need to scrape the text(plain) from `<tr id="0" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row">` to `<tr id="9" class="ui-widget-content jqgrow ui-row-ltr" role="row">`, I feel like once I get one to work I can get the others.  Because this info is not actually on the page when the page is loaded but rather comes into the fold after the page loads I am in a rutt.

With that said, here is what I have tried:

```
echo file_get_html('http://sheriffclevelandcounty.com/p2c/jailinmates.aspx')->plaintext;
```

The above will show me everything BUT the info I need, like this:

I also tried using the example from the plugin using IMDb and modified to my needs, this is it:

```
// Defining the basic cURL function
    function curl($url) {
        // Assigning cURL options to an array
        $options = Array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,  // Setting cURL's option to return the webpage data
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => TRUE,  // Setting cURL to follow 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER => TRUE, // Automatically set the referer where following 'location' HTTP headers
            CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT => 120,   // Setting the amount of time (in seconds) before the request times out
            CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 120,  // Setting the maximum amount of time for cURL to execute queries
            CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10, // Setting the maximum number of redirections to follow
            CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.1a2pre) Gecko/2008073000 Shredder/3.0a2pre ThunderBrowse/3.2.1.8",  // Setting the useragent
            CURLOPT_URL => $url, // Setting cURL's URL option with the $url variable passed into the function
        );

        $ch = curl_init();  // Initialising cURL
        curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);   // Setting cURL's options using the previously assigned array data in $options
        $data = curl_exec($ch); // Executing the cURL request and assigning the returned data to the $data variable
        curl_close($ch);    // Closing cURL
        return $data;   // Returning the data from the function
    }

     // Defining the basic scraping function
    function scrape_between($data, $start, $end){
        $data = stristr($data, $start); // Stripping all data from before $start
        $data = substr($data, strlen($start));  // Stripping $start
        $stop = stripos($data, $end);   // Getting the position of the $end of the data to scrape
        $data = substr($data, 0, $stop);    // Stripping all data from after and including the $end of the data to scrape
        return $data;   // Returning the scraped data from the function
    }

    $scraped_page = curl("http://sheriffclevelandcounty.com/p2c/jailinmates.aspx");    // Downloading IMDB home page to variable $scraped_page
    $scraped_data = scrape_between($scraped_page, '<table id="tblII" class="ui-jqgrid-btable" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" role="grid" aria-multiselectable="false" aria-labelledby="gbox_tblII" style="width: 456px;">', '</table>');   // Scraping downloaded dara in $scraped_page for content between <title> and </title> tags

    echo $scraped_data; // Echoing $scraped data, should show "The Internet Movie Database (IMDb)"
```

Of course neither of these work, so my question is: How do I use the PHP Simple DOM Parser to get dynamic content that is loaded after page load?  Is it possible or am I just completely on the wrong track here?

Comment: I have the same problem. I don't use curl but I can't get my head around getting an updated version of the DOM in my PHP file. See:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321439/how-to-get-the-current-state-of-dom-in-php

Comment: Have you found any solution? I've the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35445512/how-get-content-from-a-list-when-its-shown-by-click-using-php-simple-html-dom

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you need the dynamic data that comes in the jqgrid. For that you can use post URL which in response gives the data.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://sheriffclevelandcounty.com/p2c/jqHandler.ashx?op=s");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array(
'rows'=>10000, //Here you can specify how many records you want
't'=>'ii'
    ));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo "<pre>";
print_r(json_decode($output));
```